# is there a way to prevent iframe onload from gaining focus (in chrome,opera,safari)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

i am making a plugin that creates a select with ul/lis and fake the original select's functionality. when hovering over options (lis) it appends iFrame(in-case of a url) or img in-case of an image to an element and then set their src.

The issue is when iframe triggers load it also gains focus and therefore cause focusout on the ul and close it.

This only happened in Chrome, Opera, Safari. is there a way to prevent the iFrame from gaining focus when load is triggered ?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried `event.preventDefault()` in the load?

Comment: Nope. preventDefault did not help. :-(

Comment: I guess the worst case solution is to write your own focus manager. It shouldn't actually be that hard.

Comment: well what i ended up doing was in my focusout bound i check if frame was triggered, and on the iframe focus i clear that / shift focus back to the item i need it on. Thanks